# logout action of spring security gives 302 error on mobile apps request. Is there any solution from server side?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have upgraded my project from grails 1.3.7 to grails 2.3.11. For which I have to upgraded spring security version which is spring-security-core=1.2.7.3 to spring-security-core:2.0-RC5. But after successfully upgraded when I make ajax call to logout action of spring security from android or ios app. It gives 302 response from server as spring security logout function redirect to somewhere else. Please help me to find a solution of that from server side only as I don't want to change in app.

Thanks

Comment: It might not be related but you can try to use RC4. I've got several projects running on spring-security-core:2.0-RC4, and I tried to upgrade to RC5 and everything stopped working. Weird since a RC version is supposed to change only to fix bugs, shouldn't introduce api changes and never break backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can solve this issue by making two actions,one for desktop browsers and other for mobile app.And after getting logout request from mobile apps on the server side you can avoid redirection.